# Windows 8 Froze

Tags: windows-8, crash

My laptop running Windows 8, had it's first hiccup. It's been running super smooth, and I still believe it's a rock solid OS, but it froze and I have no idea what happened. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> did nothing. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Escape</kbd> also did nothing.

Tapping my power button (usually put the computer to sleep) did nothing. My mouse was frozen. My desktop + XBox Music app combo stood still. Music stopped playing. Yet, the artist picture was animated (in XBox Music). Where would I begin to start debugging this. Is there an error log or something I could look into?

Answer (score 0):

I think restarting the machine with a hard shut off and then re-booting may fix the bug.

I personally don't believe Windows 8 has a Error/Bug console/log. Other people besides you seem to be having a lot of problems as well and have the same question as you:

http://www.forumswindows8.com/general-discussion/windows-8-error-log-367.htm

Answer (score 0):

There is an event log that you could use (windows key -> type 'event log' -> under settings heading -> view event logs) but I don't think that will help you in this case. I have had a similar problem with my Windows 8 computer intermittently, and I would bother spending time debugging it unless it becomes a major issue (happening frequently).

I would recommend keeping on top of your windows updates, and just waiting for it to be patched out.

When the bug  comes up for me, I just hard reboot and it goes away for another month or so (been using windows 8 since September)